# Laravel Eloquent Retrieving only certain rows basing on relation field

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a number of models and I have the relationships set up correctly I believe.

I want to retrieve all of the models from a table if and only if the `active` column of a foreign key table is true.

I have tried a number of variations but to no avail.

Below is the set up.

The table is question is called `device`, which points to a table called `dep`.

The `DEVICE` model has the following relationship to DEP

```
public function dep() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Dep');

}
```

The `DEP` model has a column called `active`, which is set to `true` or `false`.

What eloquent command should I use to return all `Devices` where the `active` field of the `DEP` table is true?

At the moment I am having to get all the `DEP` models and then only get the devices if the active field is set to true but I am sure there must be a more elegant approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit the results based on the existence of a field in a related model, you want to take a look at the [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method.

```
$devices = Device::whereHas('dep', function($query) {
    $query->where('active', '=', true); // Replace true with 1 if you aren't using casts
})->get();
```

This will get all devices that have a `dep` with the `active` field of true. This will not fetch `dep` along with the `Device` though. If you want that, then just use `whereHas` with eager loading as you normally would do like this:

```
$devices = Device::with('dep')->whereHas('dep', function($query) {
    $query->where('active', '=', true);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add a filter to your relationship:

```php
public function dep() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Dep')->where('active', true);
}
```

Or, if you prefer to keep the `dep` relation unaltered, you can consider to add another relation to retrieve only the active models:

```php
public function depActive() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Dep')->where('active', true);
}
```

This will return all the `DEP` models related to a `Device`, having `active = 1`.

You can use the relation as follow:

```
$depActives = $device->depActive;
```

or

```
$depActives = $device->depActive()->get();
```

boh of them will do the same

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.  But what would the Eloquent command be to get only those Devices where the DEP active field is true?  I tried, DEP::depActive()... but got the following error: Non-static method App\Device::depActive() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: The actual line of code was:  $data[] = Device::depActive()->get(); which caused the "Non-static method App\Device::depActive() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context" error.

Comment: I actually want all of the DEVICE models who's DEP is active.  I don't need the DEP model at all in this case.  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Doesn't "Devices::with('dep')->where('active', true)->get();" assume that the DEVICES table has an active field?  If I am reading it right it would return th DEP model with the DEVICE and only return Devices that have a field called "active" set to true.  My Devices table has no such field.

Comment: No, it will join the `Device` table with the `dep` table (using your `dep` relation ) then it will filter the joined table by the `active` field

Comment: It does not join the tables. It uses two separate queries.

Comment: That returns an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder object

Comment: @ThomasKim : you're right, didn't remember that eager doens't join the tables :D